# Redirecting case insensitibe URL in apache

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting, redirect

As windows has restrictions with case sensitive folder names, I would like to redirect all the request that comes with uppercase 
to lowercase folder name

```
All the request from 
www.example.com/asset/FLASH/../..

to be redirected to 
www.example.com/asset/flash/../..
```

I'm trying the below rule and it dosent seem to work. Can you seggest what can be done to resolve this

```
RewriteRule ^/asset/[flash|FLASH]$ /asset/flash? [R=301,NC] [L]
```

Comment: You should enable and check the debug logs for the rewrite module ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2,
[LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) to troubleshoot your rule. Maybe a `^/asset` instead of `^asset` ?

Comment: It's `(flash|FLASH)`, not `[flash|FLASH]` (one character among f, l,a ,s, h, |, F, L, A, S, H) and the flags have to be together (`[R=301,NC,L]`, not `[R=301,NC] [L]`). But your `NC` flag should already handle the case. To convert case on the fly, you need RewriteMap and its builtin `int:tolower` function.